# signInWithCustomToken firebase - user not staying logged in

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building an app (Main App) that authenticates through a seperate app (Auth App). I am able to `signInWithCustomToken` but the auth state does not persist between client browser refreshes even though `onAuthStateChanged` runs with the user after `signInWithCustomToken`.
Below is the authentication flow:

1. Users open the Main App, and click a button to open a popup that displays the Auth App.

   ```
   window.open(AUTH_URL, 'window', 'width=400,height=600');
   ```
2. On the Auth App users create a Firebase account with email and
   password.

   ```
   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
   ```
3. The Auth App makes a request to the Auth App's server to
   generate a custom token.

   ```
   //  client side code
   const idToken = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
   const token = api.generateTokenAPIRequest(idToken);

   // server side code
   const generateTokenAPIRequest = (idToken) => {
     const { uid } = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
     return await admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid);
   };
   ```
4. This custom token is passed back to the Main App via a `postMessage`.

   ```
   window.opener.postMessage({ token }, APP_URL);
   window.close();
   ```
5. When the Main App receives the authentication message, it signs the user in with the custom token.

   ```
   window.onmessage = (e: MessageEvent) => {
     if (e.origin !== AUTH_URL) { return; }
     const { idToken } = e.data;
     if (!idToken) return;

     firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(idToken)
   };
   ```
6. I listen to `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`. This function runs correctly with the new user account but does NOT run again when I refresh the page. It is as if the user is not being stored in the Main App's storage.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this was caused by an unrelated bug where `firebase.auth().signOut()` was being called unexpectedly. However I wanted to call out a few items in case someone stumbles upon this.

1. Make sure your service account is the same one you are using on your authenticated app. You can generate an Admin service account through the Firebase Console.
2. The post message approach has problems where a hacker can grab the ID token, sign in with it and then do all the actions the users can do. Make sure you check the `origin` of the post message like I do above. There are additional measures that can probably be put in place. I believe this is how the typical "Sign in with Google" works.
3. There are approaches with sessions that have been posted on Medium. Namely https://dev.to/johncarroll/how-to-share-firebase-authentication-across-subdomains-1ka8 and https://dev.to/brianburton/cross-domain-firebase-authentication-a-simple-approach-337k
4. Supporting this use case is currently an open issue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2303

Happy coding!